# JavaFx launch application and continue

Tags: java, javafx

I have the following 3 lines of code:

```
1 System.out.println("Starting program...");
2 Application.launch((Gui.class));
3 System.out.println("Continuing program...");
```

The problem is that when javafx application started the code after line 2 is not executed until I close javafx application. What is the right way to start javafx application and execute line 3 when javafx application is still running?

**EDIT 1** 

The only solution I found up till now is:

```
2 (new Thread(){
      public void run(){
        Application.launch((Gui.class));
       }
  }).start();
```

Is this solution normal and safe for javafx application?

Comment: Can you explain what you are actually trying to do? Normally you should think of the start(...) method as the application entry point, and have nothing except launch(...) in the main(...) method (if you even have a main(...) method).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure what you're trying to do, but `Application.launch` also waits for the application to finish which is why you're not seeing the output of line 3 immediately. Your application's `start` method is where you want to do your setup. See [the API docs for the Application class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/application/Application.html) for more information and an example.

Edit: if you want to run multiple JavaFX apps from a main thread, maybe this is what you need:

```
public class AppOne extends Application
{
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage)
    {
        Scene scene = new Scene(new Group(new Label("Hello from AppOne")), 600, 400);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println("Starting first app");
        Platform.runLater(() -> {
            new AppOne().start(new Stage());
        });
        System.out.println("Starting second app");
        Platform.runLater(() -> {
            new AppTwo().start(new Stage());
        });
    }
}

public class AppTwo extends Application
{
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage)
    {
        Scene scene = new Scene(new Group(new Label("Hello from AppTwo")), 600, 400);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }    
}
```

This runs multiple apps from the main thread by running their start methods on the JavaFX thread. However, you will lose the `init` and `stop` lifecycle methods because you're not using `Application.launch`.

Comment: I understand what you are talking about but I need the way I wrote.

Comment: You can't do it that way. If you want to do something as soon as the application starts running, you need to use either `init` (not on the JavaFX thread) or `start` (on the JavaFX thread).

Comment: Please do not vote down this answer. As I said: what you ask is impossible. The API docs I linked to literally say: "The launch method does not return until the application has exited".

Comment: Ok. I will upvote it if I don't find solution during three days.

Comment: I get Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Toolkit not initialized. When I run Platform.runLater(() -> { new  appOne().start(new Stage()); });

Comment: to anyone with the `Toolkit` problem, insert this code `new JFXPanel()` before `Platform.runLater` (see: [JavaFX Toolkit Not Initialized (Solved) | Rob's Blog](https://rterp.wordpress.com/2015/04/04/javafx-toolkit-not-initialized-solved/))