# How does the code execute after new Scene starts

Tags: java, javafx

I have a scene which is loaded, and I load another scene from the existing scene.

After loading, the new scene, I had some other code that I wanted to execute (posting some data to the event bus).

Here is the code:

```
stage.close();
home.start(stage);

System.out.println("How does the code get here?");
EventBus.getDefault().post(new LoginEvent(...);
```

I understand how line 1,2 function. However, after line 2 I thought the controller class presently being used stops running as the new scene takes over. Can someone explain, how both the new scene is started and the code continue to the print statement?

Does this mean that even though I closed the present scene, the present controller is still being used?

Edit 1: `home` is the class that contains the method for the new Scene and starts the new window. `stage` is `button.getScene().getWindow()` where button is some button that user presses in order to start the new scene.

Edit 2: My question is not duplicate of the linked because the question I had was about how the code continues and the thread was not blocked. I was thinking of a gui class different. However, Fabian's answer cleared my confusion.

Thank You!

Comment: It would help if you confirmed what exactly `home` and `stage` are. I can make a guess, but it's best to be specific.

Comment: Home is the class that contains the method for the new scene!

And stage is button.getScene().getWindow();

I will add an edit to my question!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaFx launch application and continue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30443322/javafx-launch-application-and-continue)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loading/showing a new scene does not block the thread. In fact it would be bad if you block the thread, since this would freeze the GUI by preventing the thread from doing it's job (layout, rendering, event handling ect.).

An application's start method or similar methods simply set up some data that is later used by the application thread for the layout/rendering.

It (very roughly) works similar to the following non-GUI program:

```
public class Application {

    private List<String> data;

    public void start(List<String> data) {
        // set up initial data
        data.add("Hello World");
        data.add("42");
        this.data = data;
    }

    public void handleInput(String input) {
        // react to user input
        data.clear();
        data.add("Your input was: " + input);
    }

}
```

```
public class Launcher {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> data = new ArrayList<>();
        Application app = new Application();
        app.start(data);
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("the current data is: " + data); // "render"
        String line;
        while (!"exit".equals(line = scanner.nextLine())) { // loop is done by the framework
            app.handleInput(line); // handle input event
            System.out.println("the current data is: " + data); // "render"
        }
    }
}
```